# JSF commandbutton id inside datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable

How can I add in commandbutton inside datatable?

```
<hx:dataTableEx value="#{searchData.searchFriends}" var="s">
   <hx:columnEx>
    <f:facet name="header">
     <h:outputText value="First Name" />
    </f:facet>
    <hx:requestLink action="#{pc_Search.doAddFriendAction}">
     <h:outputText value="Add as Friend" />
     <f:param name="friendId" value="#{s.memberId}" />
    </hx:requestLink>
   </hx:columnEx>
  </hx:dataTableEx>
```

To get the data at backend

```
String friendId = (String)getRequestParam().get("friendId");
```

But once I change the requestlink to command button the friedId = null? any idea how can i pass value using command button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the datatable value in a [`DataModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html). Then you can obtain the selected row by [`DataModel#getRowData()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html#getRowData%28%29).

```
public class Bean {
    private List<Friend> friends;
    private DataModel friendsModel;

    public Bean () {
        friends = getItSomehow();
        friendsModel = new ListDataModel(friends);
    }

    public void addAsFriend() {
        Friend selectedFriend = (Friend) friendsModel.getRowData();
        // ...
    }
}
```

with

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.friendsModel}" var="friend">
    <h:column>
        <h:commandButton value="Add as friend" action="#{bean.addAsFriend}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Should work as good with IBM Faces Client Framework (those `hx:` components).